# Somewhere inside my loop it's not appending results to a list. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have two files/dictionaries I want to compare, using a binary search implementation (yes, this is very obviously homework).

One file is

**american-english**

```
Amazon
Americana
Americanization
Civilization
```

And the other file is

**british-english**

```
Amazon
Americana
Americanisation
Civilisation
```

The code below should be pretty straight forward. Import files, compare them, return differences. However, somewhere near the bottom, where it says `entry == found_difference:` I feel as if the debugger skips right over, even though I can see the two variables in memory being different, and I only get the final element returned in the end. Where am I going wrong?

```
# File importer
def wordfile_to_list(filename):
    """Converts a list of words to a Python list"""

    wordlist = []

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            wordlist.append(line.rstrip("\n"))

    return wordlist

# Binary search algorithm
def binary_search(sorted_list, element):
    """Search for element in list using binary search. Assumes sorted list"""
    matches = []

    index_start = 0
    index_end = len(sorted_list)
    while (index_end - index_start) > 0:
        index_current = (index_end - index_start) // 2 + index_start
        if element == sorted_list[index_current]:
            return True
        elif element < sorted_list[index_current]:
            index_end = index_current
        elif element > sorted_list[index_current]:
            index_start = index_current + 1
        return element


# Check file differences using the binary search algorithm
def wordfile_differences_binarysearch(file_1, file_2):
    """Finds the differences between two plaintext lists,
    using binary search algorithm, and returns them in a new list"""

    wordlist_1 = wordfile_to_list(file_1)
    wordlist_2 = wordfile_to_list(file_2)

    matches = []

    for entry in wordlist_1:
        found_difference = binary_search(sorted_list=wordlist_2, element=entry)
        if entry == found_difference:
            pass
    else:
        matches.append(found_difference)

    return matches


# Check if it works
differences = wordfile_differences_binarysearch(file_1="british-english", file_2="american-english")
print(differences)
```

Comment: Side notes: using bisection of one file against the other won't let you find the *symmetric* difference; you'll only find words in `wordlist_1` that are missing in `wordlist_2`. Using set operations would let you find the differences trivially (`return list(set(wordlist_1 ^ wordlist_2))`. I also note that your two examples are ordered and both contain the same words, only differing in spelling, so using `zip()` over both files would let you compare the paired up words in O(N) time. That's a different test however, and requires that there are no differences that affect the sort order.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have an `else` suite for your `if` statement. Your `if` statement does nothing (it uses `pass` when the test is true, skipped otherwise).

You do have an `else` suite for the `for` loop:

```
for entry in wordlist_1:
    # ...
else:
    matches.append(found_difference)
```

A `for` loop can have an `else` suite *as well*; it is executed when a loop completes without a `break` statement. So when your `for` loop completes, the current value for `found_difference` is appended; so whatever was assigned last to that name.

Fix your indentation if the `else` suite was meant to be part of the `if` test:

```
for entry in wordlist_1:
    found_difference = binary_search(sorted_list=wordlist_2, element=entry)
    if entry == found_difference:
        pass
    else:
        matches.append(found_difference)
```

However, you shouldn't use a `pass` statement there, just invert the test:

```
matches = []
for entry in wordlist_1:
    found_difference = binary_search(sorted_list=wordlist_2, element=entry)
    if entry != found_difference:
        matches.append(found_difference)
```

Note that the variable name `matches` feels off here; you are appending words that are missing in the other list, not words that match. Perhaps `missing` is a better variable name here.

Note that your `binary_search()` function always returns `element`, the word you searched on. That'll always be equal to the element you passed in, so you can't use that to detect if a word differed! You need to unindent that last `return` line and return `False` instead:

```
def binary_search(sorted_list, element):
    """Search for element in list using binary search. Assumes sorted list"""
    matches = []

    index_start = 0
    index_end = len(sorted_list)
    while (index_end - index_start) > 0:
        index_current = (index_end - index_start) // 2 + index_start
        if element == sorted_list[index_current]:
            return True
        elif element < sorted_list[index_current]:
            index_end = index_current
        elif element > sorted_list[index_current]:
            index_start = index_current + 1
    return False
```

Now you can use a list comprehension in your `wordfile_differences_binarysearch()` loop:

```
[entry for entry in wordlist_1 if not binary_search(wordlist_2, entry)]
```

Last but not least, you don't have to re-invent the binary seach wheel, just use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def binary_search(sorted_list, element):
    return sorted_list[bisect(sorted_list, element)] == element
```

Comment: I know I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel, but as this is homework, I'm expected to do so :)

Comment: @komodovaran_: sure, but then you can use that existing implementation to validate your own, and see where you might have gone wrong. :-) The [source code is available](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/bisect.py).

Comment: I actually messed it up myself, it seems. I had it with `return False`, but now I would only get `[True, True, False, False]`, but this doesn't tell me *which*  words, so I figured if I just returned the actual false elements only I could easily find them. It doesn't seem to work however..

Comment: @komodovaran_: well, `True == entry` and `False == entry` are always going to be false.

Comment: @komodovaran_: but you just tested `entry`, so if your bisection returned `False` you know that `entry` didn't match.

Comment: I think `matches` is the wrong variable name. It should be called `difference` and be calculated with `[entry for entry in wordlist_1 if not binary_search(wordlist_2, entry)]`. Note that it's only half of the problem : `set(wordlist_1) - set(wordlist_2)`, even though `set(wordlist_1) ^ set(wordlist_2)` is needed. No need for `binary_search` or `bisect`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: yes, using set interactions is going to be much faster still. But, as the OP mentioned, when you have homework you follow the instructions. :-)

Comment: @EricDuminil: I corrected my inversion error; thanks for spotting that one!

Comment: You still need to check for `wordlist_2` words not in `wordlist_1`

Comment: @EricDuminil: we don't know if that's a requirement, but good point.

Comment: `for entry in wordlist_2:
        found_difference = binary_search(sorted_list=wordlist_1, element=entry)
        if found_difference is False:
            matches.append(entry)`

Does the trick, and returns a list of words not in the other list.

Comment: @EricDuminil: besides, if the goal is to find only words that differ in spelling, just using `[w1 for w1, w2 in zip(file1, file2) if w1 != w2]` would suffice (modulo some newline stripping).

Comment: @komodovaran_: do not use `is False`. Use `if not found_difference:`.

Comment: Sorry, did I slip again? It just seems more comprehensible if it's a variable hiding a true/false. Maybe I just worded it poorly? I could of course name it `different` and it would read like an ordinary sentence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The `zip` approach only works if the spelling difference doesn't change the order.

Comment: Many : `vimdiff /usr/share/dict/american-english /usr/share/dict/british-english` :D So for example : `['Americanising', 'Americanism']` and `['Americanism', 'Americanizing']`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: nice! I've edited my comment on the question.

Comment: Your `zip` idea was a good one. I modified it and integrated it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## With sets

Binary search is used to improve efficiency of an algorithm, and decrease complexity from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`.

Since the naive approach would be to check every word in `wordlist1` for every word in `wordlist2`, the complexity would be `O(n**2)`.

Using binary search would help to get `O(n * log n)`, which is already much better.

Using [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), you could get `O(n)`:

```
american = """Amazon
Americana
Americanization
Civilization"""

british = """Amazon
Americana
Americanisation
Civilisation"""

american = {line.strip() for line in american.split("\n")}
british = {line.strip() for line in british.split("\n")}
```

You could get the american words not present in the british dictionary:

```
print(american - british)
# {'Civilization', 'Americanization'}
```

You could get the british words not present in the american dictionary:

```
print(british - american)
# {'Civilisation', 'Americanisation'}
```

You could get the union of the two last sets. I.e. words that are present in exactly one dictionary:

```
print(american ^ british)
# {'Americanisation', 'Civilisation', 'Americanization', 'Civilization'}
```

This approach is faster and more concise than any binary search implementation. But if you really want to use it, as usual, you cannot go wrong with [@MartijnPieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46885272/6419007).

## With two iterators

Since you know the two lists are sorted, you could simply iterate in parallel over the two sorted lists and look for any difference:

```
american = """Amazon
Americana
Americanism
Americanization
Civilization"""

british = """Amazon
Americana
Americanisation
Americanism
Civilisation"""

american = [line.strip() for line in american.split("\n")]
british = [line.strip() for line in british.split("\n")]

n1, n2 = len(american), len(british)
i, j = 0, 0

while True:
    try:
        w1 = american[i]
        w2 = british[j]
        if w1 == w2:
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif w1 < w2:
            print('%s is in american dict only' % w1)
            i += 1
        else:
            print('%s is in british dict only' % w2)
            j += 1
    except IndexError:
        break

for w1 in american[i:]:
    print('%s is in american dict only' % w1)

for w2 in british[j:]:
    print('%s is in british dict only' % w2)
```

It outputs:

```
Americanisation is in british dict only
Americanization is in american dict only
Civilisation is in british dict only
Civilization is in american dict only
```

It's `O(n)` as well.

Comment: It's better to use your version here as it illustrates how you'd use this with file data, but for future reference you can also use `amercan = set(american.splitlines())`; `str.splitlines()` with no arguments or `False` removes the line separators.